# Чем больше значение первой переменной, тем меньше значение второй переменной

Tags: php

Подскажите, как решить такую задачку на php:

Есть первая переменная `var_1`, ее значение может быть от 50 до 70. И есть вторая переменная `var_2`, ее значение может быть от 150 до 100. Так вот чем больше переменная `var_1` (в диапазоне от 50 до 70), тем меньше будет вторая переменная `var_2` (в диапазоне от 150 до 100).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Формула будет такой

```php
$var_2 = 100 + (150-100) * ( 1 - ($var_1 - 50)/(70-50))
```

где

`($var_1 - 50)/(70-50)` - какую часть занимает `$var_1` от `(70-50)`

какая часть осталась `( 1 - ($var_1 - 50)/(70-50))`

`(150-100)` - сколько может быть максимум разница

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!